# Get Space information in different languages

Tags: android, here-api

Is there any way to get the Information inside a Space (e.g. space.getContent().getPlaceCategoryId()) in a different language then english?

Comment: have you tried to set the locale?

Comment: the map is on german because my phone is localized in german. The developer reference says i dont have to set anything because the map takes the phone lang and localizes everything itself.

Comment: actually i meant something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760194/locale-during-unit-test-on-android

Comment: That is not what i meant. I want to show the space categories of a venue in a list. but all categories are in english.

Comment: if the developer reference in on the web then can i look at it

Comment: https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/quick-start.html

Answer (score 0):

The HERE mobile SDK supports many different languages and the language that may be used is as described in the documentation:

> SDK for Android is a globally available product with support for many languages. HERE SDK does not require any actions from developers to set the appropriate language as it automatically detects the current device language setting and applies the same language within the SDK if it is supported. If HERE SDK does not support the device language, a fallback language, which is typically English, is used.
>
> Map labels at the street level are always displayed in the local language. For example, Central Park in Manhattan, New York is always displayed as "Central Park" irrespective of the device language setting. Names for states, provinces, regions, cities, mountains, lakes, and rivers may be localized to the language corresponding to the device language setting. For example, where the device language is set to French, the label for South Carolina reads "Caroline du Sud"; if the device language is set to Spanish, the label for New York reads "Neuva York".

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/coverage-label-languages.html