# Android UI Testing - Localized String testing

Tags: java, android, localization, android-espresso, ui-testing

This is a two part question.

1 - Does it add value to the project to check every string matches the correct widget across multiple languages for an Activity's associated UI test or should I take a different approach or just not do this at all?

2 - Assuming this is the right approach I have tried to implement the suggestion from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16760194/locale-during-unit-test-on-android/21810126). Unfortunately the locale is not updating for my UI tests and fails one of the two tests depending on the system language that I have already set on my device.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RegisterActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void test_onScreenLoadStringsDisplayedInEnglish() {
        testEnglishLocale();
        onView(withId(R.id.welcome_text_view)).check(matches(
            withText(WELCOME_EN)));
    }

    @Test
    public void test_onScreenLoadStringsDisplayedInSpanish() {
        testSpanishLocale();
        onView(withId(R.id.welcome_text_view)).check(matches(
            withText(WELCOME_ES)));
    }


    private void testEnglishLocale() {
        setLocale("en", "US");
    }

    private void testSpanishLocale() {
        setLocale("es", "ES");
    }

    private void setLocale(String language, String country) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language, country);
        // here we update locale for date formatters
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        // update locale for app resources
        Resources res = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getResources();
        Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, It does add value to test around different languages. A common issue we run in to is that UI's are designed for a local language, but often a translated language has longer verbiage than the local version. This can cause unexpected bad UI behavior, such as buttons expanding beyond the edge of a screen, or content getting pushed down. It's these rendering issues that are good to test around.

I can't comment on the second question yet. I've just started digging in to how to implement the locale change in espresso.

Comment: Did you find a solution to change the language?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fastlane to get screenshots in various languages.  fastlane will also run tests, but it doesn't appear to have options to run tests in various languages.  However, its logging out the commands it sending to the device via adb when it does the screenshots, and its doing them via tests.  Ideally, I'd add support to fastlane for running the tests in multiple languages (its open source), but it's in ruby, and I'm not really up on ruby.  I'm probably going to write a shell script.

Here's what it's doing:

Just once it installs the apk and test apk

```
adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r {path to apk}
adb -s emulator-5554 install -t -r {path to test apk}
```

Then for each language, change the argument for testlocale:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop {yourpackagename}.test
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop {yourpackagename}
adb -s emulator-5554 shell am instrument --no-window-animation -w \
-e testLocale en \
--no-hidden-api-checks \
-e appendTimestamp true \
-e package {package for tests, optionally} \
{yourpackagename}.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

BTW, there are other good reasons to run tests in multiple languages.  Some apps have per language resources (I'm using resources in a general sense, not Android resources).  And in some case may not have some resources for some languages.  It's important to test things work as expect in those cases.

Comment: And one more thing, in the tests for doing the screenshots from fastlane we have:
   `@Rule @JvmField
    val localeTestRule: LocaleTestRule = LocaleTestRule()`